Spring Modulith ApplicationEventPublisher startup failing
I'm integrating Spring Modulith in a spring-boot, JPA application.The legacy application has Its EntityManager, SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory defined, all with @Primary annotation. That's, for some reason I didn't get, is needed for the application to work.
When I tried to use the ApplicationEventPublisher, I had the error below (jpaEventPublicationRepository can't be automatically configured as It can't pick a single entityManager candidate).
My question, obviously, is how to make the spring auto-configuration understands which EM to use in the jpa publication repo? Isn't a way to indicate this explicitly ? Of course, I dont want to touch in JPA configuration of a legacy app.

Spring-Boot: 3.3.1

Spring-Modulith: 1.2.2


I tried to disable the auto-configuration, but made no difference.
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.modulith.events.config.EventPublicationAutoConfiguration
The stacktrace.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'jpaEventPublicationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/modulith/events/jpa/JpaEventPublicationAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'jpaEventPublicationRepository' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManager' 
available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [ecomEntityManager, jpaSharedEM_AWC_ecomSessionFactory, jpaSharedEM_AWC_ecomEntityManagerFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoa


The JPA-based Event Publication Registry in Spring Modulith currently expects a single EntityManager instance to qualify for dependency injection.
That said, I'd argue that your bean setup is inconsistent as the exception clearly states
more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates:
[ecomEntityManager, jpaSharedEM_AWC_ecomSessionFactory, jpaSharedEM_AWC_ecomEntityManagerFactory]

An arrangement with three bean instances marked as primary, none of them really is. So ultimately, it's not a Spring Modulith problem as you'd see the same exception everywhere you try to inject an EntityManager directly.
As a workaround, you could try to switch to the JDBC-based Event Publication Registry. That one is solely relying on a canonical DataSource instance.

The JDBC module worked. The events are persisted, but I could not see the Listener receiving it (@EnableAsync was added to boot Application,  database record reference correctly the Listener) :
listener_id: de.company.m2.ModuleListener.on(de.company.m2.event.LoginEvent)
completition_date: NULL
ps: This paSharedEM_AWC instances are actually created by Spring under the hood. There's only one EntityManager @Primary annotated explicitly by the app (the other 2 I've mentioned are not EM).

Just got what the issue was ...
The publisher method must be annotated with @Transactional. Without this, the event log is persisted but the listener is not triggered. Does this make sense to you @oliver-drotbohm ?

Actually, it doesn't. Would you mind creating a reproducer and filing a ticket with out bug tracker so that I can have a closer look?
